# c++ need unique ID for string but always same regardless of order

Tags: c++, ascii, unique, document

I need a unique ID for a document read into a c++ program that will carry into a database.  The ID needs to be the same regardless of whether the document it is tied to is run through the program first, by itself, or in the middle of a stack of other documents.  So that I can honor overwrites of the document in the database.

I considered using the ASCII value of the document name such as

Employee Spec Page.doc 358

but it has the same value as

Answer Warnings.doc 358

Which means that when I run the second doc in my program, it overwrites the presence of the first doc.

The ID must be a number and needs to be unique but it must be consistently regeneratable without having to cross-reference the database itself (since this program runs separately from the database import program)

Hoping someone has some ideas because I'm stumped.

**EDIT:** I tried to use MD5 to convert "Employee Spec Page.doc" and "Answer Warnings.doc" and got the following char representations:

Answer Warnings: 2dcb2503c48f5472bfdbafe28d565a9d
Employee Spec Page: a9be4c1428c11b406072c0bd3dab2dee

However, when I then convert the char* into an unsigned int

```
char* docID = md5.digestString(pDocument->m_csDocumentName.GetBuffer());
pDocument->m_csDocID.Format("%i",(unsigned int)docID);
```

I get both being:

Answer Warnings: 1634456
Employee Spec Page: 1634456

I got the md5 class from here: http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/md5-c-implementation/

What am I doing wrong?  I need it to be an integer or else I won't be able to store the ID in the database.

Comment: You cannot concert `char*` to `int` like this and expect to get the same results across different runs. what you get is an int that depends on where your hash is stored in memory and not on the value of the hash function.

Comment: Your can't cast from a pointer type to a non-pointer type and expect anything sensible to happen.

Comment: public:  
      // an MD5 digest is a 16-byte number (32 hex digits)  
      BYTE digestRaw[ 16 ] ;  

      // This version of the digest is actually  
      // a "printf'd" version of the digest.  
      char digestChars[ 33 ] ;

Comment: as I cannot do formattin in comments, i did suggest code changes in your post. try to compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need is a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) function generating a number big enough to avoid collisions. [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) (as piokuc above mentioned) should be ok

you can generate shorter keys by simply truncating the MD5 result. but be aware that you increase the chance of collisions. 128 bit has more than 10^38 different keys; 64 bit has more than 10^19; 32 bit has more than 10^9 (4.294.967.296). so 32 bit is near a lottery chance to have a collision between two specific documents. for 10.000 documents you have a chance of 1% thave at least one collision. the acceptance of a certain key length depends on your requirements. you can of course implement collision detection and collision resolution.

if your 'database' allows only a short key you have to implement collision resolution. for an idea of how to do that see [Hash_table Collision_resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack): '10^−18 to 10^−15 is the uncorrectable bit error rate of a typical hard disk. In theory, MD5 hashes or UUIDs, being 128 bits, should stay within that range until about 820 billion documents'

---

to your concrete library:

if you look into the md5 header file, there is

```
public:
    // an MD5 digest is a 16-byte number (32 hex digits)
    BYTE digestRaw[ 16 ] ;
```

so you can retrieve the binary digest any time

```
MD5 md5;
char* docID = md5.digestString(pDocument->m_csDocumentName.GetBuffer());
unsigned int hash_ui = *(unsigned int *)digestRaw;
```

---

Comment: That's fine if I truncate the MD5 result but that still leaves me with a hex char and I need an integer.  And truncating it at the same value would still lead to the same unsigned int representation.  How can I convert the MD5 char result to an int and still guarantee uniqueness (or at least minimal possibility of collisions)

Comment: how big is your integer?  what is the number of documents? for a 32 bit integer and 10.000 documents you have a chance of 1% to have at least one collision. are you sure you cannot have a UUID as key in your database? if you can change the key type in your db i strongly recommend that.

Comment: There is a UUID but that is something completely separate.  This is purely for the documents stored and if there is a collision, the document will be overriden.  I'm sorry but I didn't see what the code change suggestion was that you mentioned.

Comment: I changed your code to be an unsigned short int and got exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use md5 algorithm for generating the id, you'll find a free implementation easily.

Comment: That's not bad, but if I use md5 to convert each character to a hexString and then convert those characters back to integer, it gives me a really, really, long integer. Any way to make it unique and still have it no more than say 5 characters?

Comment: No miracles - if you use a shorter hash function, a CRC for example, collisions will be more be more possible. Another possibility is to simply store all the names in a table and assign them inceasing numbers, but you'll need to maintain the table and must always have it to find an id.

Comment: MD5 gives 128 bits. that's enough for avoiding collisions on reasonably sized problems. 128 bits are 16 bytes or 32 hex characters.